# desktop shortcut to phone options?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

can I have shortcut to

- airplane mode and/or
- phone options (power off/airplane mode etc)

I do not like the  current way of holding power on/off button for some time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Quick Settings](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.bwx.bequick) app puts that at your fingertips and, by default, is launched with a long-press on the search button.

Comment: long-press on the search button (very right one) gives me 'Speak now' window

Comment: Yes. With this installed (until you choose a default) it will prompt you for which action you want.

Comment: I didn't get it first time... works marvelously ... thank you Al